# How to hide the warning "This type of file can harm your computer" while downloading .xml file using Chrome Chromedriver 79 with Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Despite setting `safebrowsing.enabled` to `true` / `false`, the warning *...This type of file can harm your computer...* is still being displayed in browser. How to hide this information?

Comment: is it while download then you may try to open the file in new tab and let user save it instead of directly downloading it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable downloading of file using Chrome/[ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) hiding the warning **This type of file can harm your computer** you need to:

- Add the preferences:

  - `download.default_directory`
  - `download.prompt_for_download`
  - `download.extensions_to_open`
  - `safebrowsing.enabled`
- As well as add the following arguments to whilelist:

  - `--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection`
  - `safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist`

---

### Demonstration

To demonstrate downloading using [selenium-chromedriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-chromedriver), and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) through [java](/questions/tagged/java) I have clicked on the first `Download` link in the webpage http://www.landxmlproject.org/file-cabinet and your effective solution will be:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:/Utility/Downloads/");
  prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
  prefs.put("download.extensions_to_open", "application/xml");
  prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
  options.addArguments("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
  WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
  driver.get("http://www.landxmlproject.org/file-cabinet");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='MntnRoad.xml']//following::span[1]//a[text()='Download']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Java_Chrome_Download]

Comment: Thank you for answer. Despite using listed preferences and options, Chrome still displays mentioned information.

Comment: @TomaszWojciechowski Can't believe it. Can you update the question with your code trials please?

Comment: @DebanjabB : It was issue on specific machine. Generally, your solution works. Thank you.

Comment: @DebanjanB I tried the above solution but still getting a download dialog box. I am trying to download one jar file and have given MIME type as application/java-archive". You marked my question as duplicate but your solution does not work.

Comment: Hi @DebanajnB  your solution doesn't work in my case. I use latest chrome 80. Tried your piece of code but "This type of file can harm your computer" is still pops up and selenium is waiting until I click "Keep"

Comment: This solution is not working for me either, I trying to download deb file with `application/x-debian-package`MIME. Maybe reason why this solution exists - not all systems are marking xml files as unsave, for me my real, not webdriver chrome is not marking xml file as "dangerous" on Ubuntu machine

Comment: @ShockwaveNN Why would you use a solution of downloading **`application/xml`** files for downloading your `application/x-debian-package` files?

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm not stupid, I'm not using `application/xml` in my code for downloading deb file, but I'm trying to find a solution to for same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the Policy on our computer. It will will be apply in your driver.

[image]