# Could not set download.prompt_for_download false for avoiding popup when downloading a file in an Electron application

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, electron, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download a file with Selenium Chromedriver through Electron. As we could not handle the popup window with selecting folder to download in, I tried to avoid this popup in this way:

```
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
```

But it doesn't work. The full code is:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.default_directory", LocationUtil.getDownloadFolderPath());
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", false); // to disable security check eg. Keep or cancel button
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
ChromeDriver chromeDriver= new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Also tried to put these prefs through Capabilities but with no success.

`((MutableCapabilities) chromeDriver.getCapabilities()).setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);`
Versions are:

- ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16
- Selenium Java 3.141.59

How could I download the file in a specific directory without popup window in an Electron app? 
UPD: Tested with browser Chrome - all things are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close enough.

Apart from adding the preference of `download.prompt_for_download` to `false` you need to set a couple of more preferences as follows:

- You need to add the type of file you wish you auto download. As an example to automatically download `xml` files you need to add:

  ```
  prefs.put("download.extensions_to_open", "application/xml");
  ```
- You need to enable/disable `safebrowsing.enabled` as follows:

  ```
  prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
  ```
- Now you need to add the argument to `safebrowsing-disable-download-protection`

  ```
  options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
  ```
- Next, you need to add the argument to `safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist`

  ```
  options.addArguments("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
  ```
- Finally, to click on the element to initiate the download, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()`.

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("element_xpath"))).click();
  ```

Clubbing it up altogether, as a demonstration, to download a xml file from the [website](http://www.landxmlproject.org/file-cabinet) your effective code block will be:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.default_directory", LocationUtil.getDownloadFolderPath());
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
ChromeDriver chromeDriver= new ChromeDriver(options);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
options.addArguments("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
driver.get("http://www.landxmlproject.org/file-cabinet");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='MntnRoad.xml']//following::span[1]//a[text()='Download']"))).click();
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: ChromeDownload]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant reference discussions in:

- [How to hide the warning “This type of file can harm your computer” while downloading .xml file using Chrome Chromedriver 79 with Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840198/how-to-hide-the-warning-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-while-downloa/59841109#59841109)
- [How to download XML files avoiding the popup This type of file may harm your computer through ChromeDriver and Chrome using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407388/how-to-download-xml-files-avoiding-the-popup-this-type-of-file-may-harm-your-com/55413305#55413305)