# How to bypass or avoid the download message - This type of file may harm your computer, Do you want to keep this file ? Using webdriverIO

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

I am trying to download an apk file using webdriverIO. I kept the following args and prefs for chrome, but still ath the end of download its prompting for the message - This type of file may harm your computer, Do you want to keep this file ?. How can I skip this ?

```
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
    w3c: false,
    args: ["--reduce-security-for-testing", "--start-maximized", "--disable-gpu","--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection","--disable-web-security","disable-extensions","safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist"],
    prefs: {
      'directory_upgrade': true,
      'download.prompt_for_download': false,
      'prompt_for_download': true,
      'download.default_directory': downloadDir,
      "safebrowsing.enabled":true
    }
  },
```

Please dont mark this as duplicate, I tried the solutions provided by  :

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up](http://solution%201)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840198/how-to-hide-the-warning-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-while-downloa](http://solution%202)

but nothing worked. Please help